# Adding a [SOLD] tag to an article in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm developing a Prestashop theme for a client that sells collectors items. He only sells one of most items, and if an item is sold he would like the option to still display the item, but with something like [SOLD] in red in front of the article name, in the categories as well as the product page. How would I go about doing this, while still keeping his Prestashop installation upgrade-able?

Comment: Question to upvote, not the contrary.

Comment: would like this answer to be a comment, no rep Watch it on this website, https://bilbotruke.net/363-productos-vendidos , our sold items have a sold tag, for products of certain category IIrc i did the exact steps as the answer above, except the if refernced the id of the category (we move them to other cat after sold), and as i did it some years ago i cannot remember if there was something more to do, maybe css, our presta version is 1.6.1 with default bootstrap Hoping Damon to see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65026072/little-modification-of-the-native-search-engine-form-of

Answer (score 1):

He set the stock of the product to 1 and use the flag "out of stock" to tell it's sold (& he prevent selling of out of stock products of course).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by changing your template files.

If you are using the default theme, duplicate the theme and rename it so that it isn't overwritten when upgrading.

You can set products to be available for order or not within the backoffice. You could untick this value so that the product is technically not available for order.

You need to look at the following templates in your front-office.

`product-list.tpl`

This lists all the products for a category.  You can use the following code to test to see if a product is available for order or not .

```
{if !$product.available_for_order}
    <span style="color: red;">[SOLD]</span>
{/if}
```

You can also use this piece of code in the `product.tpl` file.